# Custom Taxonomies Cababilities

Tags: custom-taxonomy, capabilities

Since 3.1 I've had an issue with custom taxonomies for a site. it seems that my user (admin level) can't edit the taxonomies from any screen. I see them on under the custom post type and can see them when adding a new post to the custom post type. I can even add currently available taxonomies to the post but I can't create new terms or access the custom taxonomy on it's edit page. Below is my code to set up the taxonomy.

```
 <?php add_action( 'init', 'fvww_custom_taxonomies');

function fvww_custom_taxonomies() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => __( 'River Classes', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'River Class', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search River Classes' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All River Classes' ),
        'parent_item'           => __( 'Parent Class' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Class:' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit River Class' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update River Class' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New River Class' ),
        'new_item_name'         => __( 'New River Class' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'River Class' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'Class', array( 'fvww-river-guide' ), array(
        'hierarchical'              => true, //operates like a category
        'labels'                    => $labels,
        'rewrite'                   => true,
        'public'                    => true,
        'show_ui'                   => true,
        )
    ); // ends class taxonomy

} /* end function */ ?>
```

If I click on the 'Class' taxonomy under River Guides I get the 'Cheatin uh?' message from wp-admin/edit-tags.php line 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@curtismchale:**

Try `'river-class'` instead of `'Class'`, i.e.:

```
 register_taxonomy( 'river-class', array( 'fvww-river-guide' ), array(
    'hierarchical'              => true, //operates like a category
    'labels'                    => $labels,
    'rewrite'                   => true,
    'public'                    => true,
    'show_ui'                   => true,
    )
); // ends class taxonomy
```

Actually what caused you to stumble was your choice of a capitalized taxonomy name *(i.e. "Class" vs. "class")*  although I'd really recommend against such a generic name as *"class"* to avoid potential conflict which is why I suggested *"river-class"* instead.

Comment: Yup that did it. Now the bigger question is why did it work before (3.0.X) and why didn't it work now?

Comment: @curtismchale - Line 97 of `/wp-admin/admin.php` uses `sanitize_key($_GET['taxonomy'])` which converts to  lowercase and 3.0 did not do that. It's probably a regression bug but I hope they leave it in because I think keys like taxonomy names *(and post types)* should ideally be lower case.

Comment: @curtismchale - BTW, see http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16649